# bootstrap multiple modals issue must open one after another closed

Tags: php, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

Hi I have multiple  Bootsyrap modals created dynamically with php , these modal opened itself if requirements meets, I want to open one after another closed , and problem is not sure all three modals will meet requirements , some time we have 2 , some time one so I can not use modal close event as well

```
 // 1st modal

<?php if(count($getNewBadges) >0  ) { ?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#EarnBadgeModal").modal('show');
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php  echo SITE_URL; ?>/engagement/award/ajax/award_ajax.php",
      data: { action:'set_badge_popup' },
      success: function(response){   
        $("#EarnBadgeModal").modal('hide');
      }
    }); 
   
});
</script>
<?php } ?>

// 2nd modal

<?php if(count($getNewContest) >0) { ?>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#ContestUserModal").modal('show');
  $('#ContestUserModal').css('z-index', 1040);
     $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php  echo SITE_URL; ?>/engagement/leaderboard/ajax/leaderboard_ajax.php",
      data: { action:'set_contest_read' },
      success: function(response){   
      }
    }); 
   
});
 </script>
 <?php } ?>

  // 3rd modal

if(count($getPoints) >0) 
{
 ?>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#pointsUserModal<?php echo $mv; ?>").modal('show');
       $('#pointsUserModal').css('z-index', 1049);
         
      });
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

I have tried many things like below , but nothing worked

```
 <style type="text/css">
.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop {
z-index: 1051;
}

.modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop + .modal-backdrop {
 z-index: 1051;
}
</style>

 // another 
 <style type="text/css">
 .modal-backdrop:nth-child(2n-1) {
  opacity : 0;
 }
 </style>
```

Thanks Any help is appreciated

Comment: _"so I can not use modal close event as well"_ - why not? What is stopping you from checking if the next modal element actually exists, before you try to open it?

Comment: @CBroe, what if previous one not exit?

Comment: What do you mean by "previous"? Are you trying to go "backwards" at some point, or what?

Comment: @CBroe we may have ContestUserModal, EarnBadgeModal, pointsUserModal all 3 need to open , some time EarnBadgeModal, pointsUserModal only , some time EarnBadgeModal and ContestUserModal only

Comment: it all depend if user has assigned something to related modal, like if badge assigned and points assigned we will need to open badge modal and points modal not the contest modal

Comment: Then you should probably start by putting what modals you need to call, what data you need to send to what URL, and what needs to be done with the response, into an array data structure. Then you can process one item out of that, and when you are done, move on to the next one.

Comment: @CBroe noted, Will try this Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did like this as @Cbroe advised and its working fine now , added a class on bootstrap close button .closeModal

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
  for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
    $(modalArr[0]).modal('show');
    modalArr.shift();
  }
  });


$(".closeModal").on('click', function()
{ 
for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
$(modalArr[0]).modal('show');
 modalArr.shift();
}

});

console.log(modalArr);

</script>
```